# Necesito obtener solamente el token de acceso de este json

Tags: api, symfony4

Hola necesito obtener solamente el `access_token` de este json, estuve leyendo y encontré algo de la función json_decode la implemente pero en postman me devuelve lo siguiente:

> The controller must return a "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response" object but it returned null. Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?"

ojo que es una api en symfony que estoy haciendo. La consulta de obtención de autorización se realiza perfectamente pues obtengo este resultado:

```
"{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 7200,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI4IiwianRpIjoiNTdmZTMyOGMzOTFjMTY2NWY0MTJmYzgxMDJmMjYwMGVlZmVmNWU2ZTVmNTYwZjM2YTk3MTgyY2M2YWM2OGNlYjU2NmUxOTljYjJmMTE2MDUiLCJpYXQiOjE1OTE1NTk1MDUsIm5iZiI6MTU5MTU1OTUwNSwiZXhwIjoxNTkxNTY2NzA1LCJzdWIiOiI2Iiwic2NvcGVzIjpbImdldF9oaXN0b3J5IiwiZ2V0X3JlYWx0aW1lIl19.XoyLWQQTMSpALuDm_GE6O2YKMcUS497pUw81BXLt3E8JLsLmfa6EH4xoxWIlLVthGJRPcACZNeYCMR0FQPEqtviqR82DTRpHZ_XduArzO7pJ97gCJRyIZckgGsbwuH0M3CLjxg4CZeqr7aZAsmHNlUSLCPYwu7KhGlbGrO3i-PJoSCc3FJsfwUXHWNhcXNKUJzjY7FkVzKPW8s8U8gxrXCBayVakv4SbPPJgq01MpDBkvHacP6DjvlfrZ7oR39R4bLmX8O_8fpj-PGHysNW1NRgJhqvBpRvZ9EJ6ZhZvl6OhcrWe5yk3BTY59ycPHNZ7soic26uIdD28oATh-czhasG99bUqpFE7OSug71lutiRoXJTfaMZeuq0jap-ThqwWfjJ-W1f6Dh2EHNQJTN3FjbQPe4SyiVXm6PkG3rJikenCf_P5yEGXIPk_d7RRjak0J_W1vFhz-tsfaoJIolF23k7WQYxpX4s15mTfyyw-xym7Pdq8U3BN_JmAxpQXQJAkU9PhtavES8Z7YvVqhco8r6rzIsqHvAji19zj-ldxwahUeEn3WuPUx3wxi-KW0_L4q_u_QAQxWQ-z6Lks0HzsFj9C9v5IlZfpEwvPZuAKDwkT4Obz2ef5TqPfzHpXexCM8QYOsxfLGyrTCd2hH8POj4qU2doQajgBWt79ySBvX-Y",
    "refresh_token": "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"

}"
```

que es el resultado esperado, el problema es que necesito obtener el access_token solamente para después pasarlo en otro método en el header.

Comment: El error te dice que en algún controlador (no indicas cual) estas devolviendo un null, cuando es obligatorio devolver un objeto de tipo response. Por ello el error no debe estar relacionado con lo del token que mencionas. Puedes poner el código de la action que te da el error?

Comment: /**
       * @Route("login1", name="login1", methods={"GET"})
       */
     public function gettoken(){
      $token= $this->login();
      return $token;
  } la funcion login es la que me devuelve el json, lo capturo y quisiera devolver solo el access_token que esta dentro de ese json

Answer (score 1):

Symfony te obliga a devolver un objeto de tipo response debido a su arquitectura. Si lo que quieres es devolver un json, puedes crear un objeto jsonResponse(). Tu controlador debe ser algo como:

```
/** * @Route("login1", name="login1", methods={"GET"}) */
public function getToken()
{
    $token= $this->login(); 
    $resp = new JsonResponse($token) ;
    return $resp; 
}
```

Dado que jsonResponse cumple con el interfaz de response, está respuesta sería correcta.

Nota: revisa tu api, puesto que también deberás devolver las cabeceras correspondientes a json. Esta es una de las razones por las que necesitas un objeto response, pues también debes devolver las cabeceras correctas.

Comment: y si yo quisiera solo pasar el access_token luego por la cebecera de otro metodo??

Comment: Revisa los métodos que tiene el objeto jsonresponse. Los hay para rellenar cabeceras, query, y otros...

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado estimados amigos, en esta linea solo se obtiene el accesstoken, 
json_decode((string)$response->getContent(),true)['access_token']